# UIView.animation does not work properly when I add new label with constraints to the View

Tags: swift, animation, constraints

UIView.animation does not work as it was, when I add new label with constraints

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                    self.answerLabels[i].center.y =  self.view1.center.y + self.wordMainLabel.frame.height/2 + self.answerLabels[i].frame.height/2

                })
```

this code works until I add a new label with constraints to the view1

Comment: Animate the constraint constant rather than the center.y

Comment: this code works. but when I add a new label into view1, it animates ridiculously